# In Wagtail is there a way to have a listing/index page list sub pages in a manually specified order without the InlinePanel listing every field?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I want to have a page (/blog/) that lists sub-pages. But I don't want to order them by most recent or anything like that. I want to order them in a manually specified way.

I'd love to use an Orderable on the sub-pages, but the only way I've been able to get that to work is if I use an InlinePanel. The problem with an InlinePanel, is then Wagtail will show each page inlined with every field, and each page can be *really* *long*. Is there a way to use InlinePanel, but only show the title of each page vs. every single field?

Or is there a better way to do this in Wagtail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the Folder icon corresponding to your top-level blog page (in the Pages flyout menu), you can then click the SORT header and drag/drop to re-order the child pages.